# Is Doctrine really that slow?

Tags: php, performance, doctrine

I am using a Doctrine in my application but it seems that it really slows down my application. A simple code like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('co.id')
        ->from('CounterOnline co')
        ->where('co.user_id = ?', $user_id)
        ->orWhere('co.ip = ?', $ip)
        ->limit(1);
$counter_online = $q->fetchOne();
```

takes 0.025206089019775 second to execute. I do a lot of DB queries in my application so that time is a terrible result.

Is Doctrine really that slow or somehow my configuration may be messed up? Caching isn't really an option, because most of the servers don't have neither memcache nor APC installed.

Comment: That's an average speed or speed of the first call? My guess is that you should test that exact same query without doctrine and see if it's going faster. 2-3ms for a query isn't that slow.

Comment: 2-3ms is not bad, but 25ms is quite much and will be a problem in production environment with lots of users.

Answer (score 3):

Put your query in a loop that runs the query 100 times, and compare the execution time.

If it scales linearly (i.e. from 0.025206 seconds to 2.5206 seconds), you have a problem with your database or possibly your Doctrine installation (not Doctrine itself, because no one would use it if that kind of time was normal). Make sure your database is properly indexed and/or normalized, if possible.

If it scales non-linearly (i.e. from 0.025206 seconds to 0.0292 seconds), your application is probably connecting to a remote database, not a local one, and the majority of the execution time is the TCP/IP overhead surrounding establishing the connection to the database--the small delta in execution time reflects that the queries themselves run just fine. Double-check your application's configuration files to make sure it's connecting to the right database.

Answer (score 2):

Performance could depend on a lot of things:

- Fields indexed or not
- Amount of data in your table
- Hardware
- ORM
- ...

However, I guess that for such a simple query, the problem should not be Doctrine here.